# "Moving" UIViews across UIViewControllers in custom transition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

You know how in some apps, when the app enters a custom transition between two `UIViewController`s, the animation makes it seem as if a UIView is moving "from" a `UIViewController` across "to" the appearing `UIViewController`? Like in the Duolingo app, when you tap a lesson group on the main screen, the icon of the lesson group magnifies and becomes the "header" of the lesson group page. How do we do that? How do we "share" `UIView`s between `UIViewController`s in custom transitions? (Assuming that we use the iOS 8 APIs such as `UIPresentationController` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.)

Comment: Take a look at this Apple's sample: [LookInside](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LookInside/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014643).

Comment: @ImanouPetit I don't see the animation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create three of the same views: `fromView`,`toView` and `transitionView`.

when `transitionView` animating, set `fromView` and `toView`'s hiden to YES.

when `transitionView` animate finish, set `fromView` and `toView` to hiden to NO, and remove `transitionView`.

you also need `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

more detail you can read [this code](https://github.com/boycechang/BCMagicTransition).